# Unable to retrieve user mail and profile photo into profile fragment

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, google-signin

Needed help with this issue.

Thanks in Advance!

In the app, once the user logged in, mail and profile photo of user should be displayed in the profile fragment. But, it's not working

We are using SharedPreferences to fetch details

//Here's ProfileFragment.java

```
package app.com.example.android.diary;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.android.diary.R;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;

public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

Button signOut;

private TextView nameTextView;
private ImageView profileImageView;

String name;
String profilePicURL, personPhoto;

PersistentDeviceStorage persistentDeviceStorage;
GoogleSignInResult sig;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    persistentDeviceStorage = PersistentDeviceStorage.getInstance(getContext());


    GoogleSignInAccount acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getContext());
    if (sig.isSuccess()) 
    {
        personPhoto = String.valueOf(acct.getPhotoUrl());
    }

    persistentDeviceStorage.setName(acct.getDisplayName());
    persistentDeviceStorage.setProfileUrl(personPhoto);

    profilePicURL = persistentDeviceStorage.getProfileUrl();
    name = persistentDeviceStorage.getName();

    signOut = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.signOut);
    profileImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);

    nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.username);
    nameTextView.setText(name);

    if (profilePicURL != null) {
        Glide.with(this)
                .load(profilePicURL)
                .fitCenter()
                .into(profileImageView);

        signOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                persistentDeviceStorage.setEmail("null");
                persistentDeviceStorage.setToken("null");
                persistentDeviceStorage.setProfileUrl("null");
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                if (getActivity() != null) {
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    return view;
}
```

}
PersistentDeviceStrorage.java seems to work fine, but the changes aren't reflecting in the app.

//Here's PersistentDeviceStorage.java

```
public class PersistentDeviceStorage{

private static PersistentDeviceStorage persistStorage = null;

private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

public synchronized static PersistentDeviceStorage getInstance(Context context) {
    if (persistStorage == null) {
        persistStorage = new PersistentDeviceStorage(context);
    }
    return persistStorage;
}

private PersistentDeviceStorage(Context context) {
   // sharedPreferences= Activity.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
            //sharedPreferences,0);
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
}




public String getEmail()
{
    return sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.EMAIL_ID, "null");
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(Constants.EMAIL_ID, email);
    editor.apply();
    editor.commit();
}

public void setName(String name) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(Constants.NAME, name);
    editor.apply();
    editor.commit();
}

public String getName() {

    return sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.NAME, "NoName");
}


public void setToken(String token) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(Constants.TOKEN, token);
    editor.apply();
    editor.commit();
}

public String getToken() {
    return sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.TOKEN, "null");
}

public void setProfileUrl(String url) {
    if(url!=null) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(Constants.PROFILE_URL, url);
        editor.apply();
        editor.commit();
    }
}

public String getProfileUrl() {
    return sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.PROFILE_URL, "null");
}

}
```

Comment: profileImageView.setBackground(null); why are you doing this??

Comment: First of all, you won't need `apply()` and `commit()` both at once. You should have to use either `apply()`(asynchronous) or `commit()`(synchronous) on sharedPreference editor.

Comment: Where are you calling `setName` and `setProfileUrl`?

Comment: In signout.setonclicklistener...but that's when user signs out (placing everything null)..

Comment: Yes you set it to null when they sign out, but how do you set it when they sign in?

Comment: I tried using the following code snippet..but it's not working

Comment: Ohh!.. setName and setProfileUrl methods are being called right at the beginning..when the user logs in..(in the main activity)

Comment: Please provide how you call that